# Sorting of NSDictionary Array in iphone app

Tags: iphone, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have to sort the following array objects in either ascending or descending order.

```
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"key1", @"key2", @"key3",
                                          @"key4", @"key5", nil];
NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"0", @"2", @"1",
                                             @"5", @"0", nil];
NSDictionary*  dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects
                                                        forKeys:keys];
for (id key in [dictionary allKeys]) {
    NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", key, [dictionary objectForKey:key]);
}
```

My output should be like this.

```
key: key4, value:5
key: key2, value:2
key: key3, value:1
key: key1, value:0
key: key5, value:0
```

Comment: `for(id key in [dictionary allKeys]) { ... }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to sort by your values. While a `NSDictionary` is not sorted, you can get an array of the keys sorted in a way you like. Just have a look at

```
- (NSArray *)keysSortedByValueUsingSelector:(SEL)comparator
- (NSArray *)keysSortedByValueWithOptions:(NSSortOptions)opts usingComparator:(NSComparator)cmptr
```

Then iterate over the keys in that array and fetch the matching value from the dictionary.